# How to perform bitwise operations in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Suppose I have this MAC address:

```
04:f0:21:38:f5:a3
```

I am looking for a way in Ansible to modify this. In this case I need to do the following:

Set the least 4 significant bits to 0.
Flip the 7th bit.

So that the result is:

```
06:f0:21:38:f5:a0
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Ansible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>I'm not sure what does "*Set the least 4 significant bits to 0. Flip the 7th bit.*" mean, but here is the method for you to customise:</sup>

As of 2.10, I don't see a way to perform bitwise operations in Jinja2, so write a custom filter (place it in `filter_plugins/bitwise_filters.py` under the playbook dir):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'bitwise_and': self.bitwise_and
        }

    def bitwise_and(self, a, b):
        c = a & b
        return c
```

Use the custom filter along with `hwaddr` filter:

```
debug:
  msg: "{{'04:f0:21:38:f5:a3'|hwaddr('int') | bitwise_and('00:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'|hwaddr('int')) | hwaddr('linux')}}"
```

Comment: There are some hacks possible, just in case: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/249

Comment: I'm confused... I tried with [`and_`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.and_) yesterday and it produced an error, but looking closely, it shows the template translated to `msg: \"{{ (1).__and__(3) }}\"` followed by an `exception: 'int object' has no attribute 'and_'`. On the other hand `__and__` (written explicitly) works ok.