# Ansible: bitwise oprations inside anisble playbook

Tags: ansible, bit-manipulation, operators

I am trying to use bitwise operation inside my ansible playbooks. As sugegsted in this post ([How to perform bitwise operations in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550786/how-to-perform-bitwise-operations-in-ansible)), I have created the .py file for **"bitwise or"** filter and placed under default filterplugin dir
**/usr/share/ansible/plugins/filter**

1)The ansible **ansible.cfg** file is edited to specify the filter plugin path.

**filter_plugins = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/filter**

2)Ansible version on controller node is:  **3.6.10**

But unfortunately  playbook is not able to find the new defined filter. I am not sure if I am missing anything. Is there anything else I need to do?

Any help with this is appreciate.

Comment: Make sure the path to your filters is properly configured. See  ``ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_FILTER_PLUGIN_PATH``. [edit] the question and make it [mre], i.e all necessary details, directories, error messages ... minimal! complete! reproducible! You must provide all the information anybody, willing to help you, can **reproduce** your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I was away for few weeks just checking your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The filter plugin I tried is working now. There was a small coding issue inside my filter python file,  which was reported by playbook run logs on the console, that I didn't spot.

After carefully looking into the logs, I could fix the coding issue and, after that, the filter operation was found from the filter_plugin path that was specified in the ansible.cfg file.

```
filter_plugins = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/filter
```

There was no more setting needed apart from specifying the filter path in ansible.cfg.